# Excel VBA Run-time error '13' Type mismatch8

Tags: excel, vba

I have done a "copy and paste" to  a value  after comparing the "road"  number and the code number. If those two are matching, Excel VBA will copy and paste in a cell defined.  I have created a loop to repeat it. But I discovered that  up to 7000 my program was working properly, and when I replaced 7000 by 30000, Excel VBA displays

`"Run-time error '13' Type mismatch "`

after a certain time. I dont know why. Below is my program:

```
Private Sub assigment()
Dim road   As Double
Dim code As Double
Dim i  As Double

For i = 4 To 30000
   For code = 2 To 22
    For road = 4 To 65
       If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("assignment").Cells(i,  6)=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SSUSE").Cells(3, code) Then
          If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("assignment").Cells(i, 8) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SSUSE").Cells(road, 1) Then
              ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SSUSE").Cells(road, code).Copy ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("assignment").Cells(i, 10) 
         End If
       End If
    Next
   Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This will run much quicker if you store the values in the ranges into arrays. For example, v = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("assignment").Range("F4:F30000").Value

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim vSource as Variant, vCode as Variant, vRoad as Variant, vAssignment as Variant, vAddress as Variant

vSource = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("assignment").Range("F4:F30000").Value
vCode = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SSUSE").Range("B3:V3").Value
vRoad = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SSUSE").Range("A4:A65").Value
vAddress = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SSUSE").Range("B4:V65").Value
vAssignment = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("assignment").Range("H4:H30000").Value

For i = LBound(vSource,1) to UBound(vSource,1)
    For code = LBound(vCode,2) to UBound(vCode,2)
        For road = LBound(vRoad,1) to UBound(vRoad,1)
            If (vSource(i,1) = vCode(1, code)) AND (vAssignment(i,1) = vRoad(road,1)) Then
                ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("assignment").Cells(i+3, 10).Value = vAddress(Road,Code)
            End If
        Next
    Next
Next
```